# bulk_insert doesn't insert values into nullable fields

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

op.bulk_insert() isn't inserting any values into fields that are marked as "nullable=True", but it correctly inserts data into all other fields.

I know the bulk_insert() works and is valid because it successfully inserts into the other tables, and event into the same table as the one with the nullable fields, but it only inserts the data into the fields that are not nullable.

So in this case, the id, section_id, order, type, headline, and is_required fields are being filled, but the options and description fields are being left as null.

The only difference I can see between those fields and the others is that their defined as nullable.

```
def upgrade():
# ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    question = op.create_table('question',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('application_form_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('section_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('type', sa.String(length=25), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('description', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('order', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('headline', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('options', sa.JSON(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('is_required', sa.Boolean(), nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['application_form_id'], ['application_form.id'], ),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['section_id'], ['section.id'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    )

    seed_question_data(question)

def seed_question_data(question):
op.bulk_insert(question,
[

    {
        'id': 5,
        'application_form_id': 1,
        'section_id': 2,
        'type': 'long_text',
        'headline': 'headline 1',
        'description': 'Maximum 80 words.',
        'order': 4,
        'is_required': True       
    },
    {
        'id': 6,
        'application_form_id': 1,
        'section_id': 2,
        'type': 'long_text',
        'headline': 'headline 2',
        'description': 'Maximum 150 words.',
        'order': 5,
        'is_required': False       
    },
    {
        'id': 7,
        'application_form_id': 1,
        'section_id': 2,
        'type': 'file',
        'headline': 'headline 3',
        'description': 'description 3',
        'order': 6,
        'is_required': True       
    },
    {
        'id': 8,
        'application_form_id': 1,
        'section_id': 2,
        'type': 'multi-choice',
        'headline': 'headline 4',
        'description': 'description 4' ,
        'order': 7,
        'is_required': True,
        'options': [
            {'selection': 'Yes'},
            {'selection': 'No'}
        ]     
    }
```

Comment: What's the actual problem here, if there's no value to insert, and they're nullable? Not inserting to a nullable field is equivalent to explicitly setting it to NULL.

Comment: @IljaEverilä the problem is that even when there are values, it doesn't insert. I resolved this by explicitly setting the values to "None" for objects that don't have descriptions and options.

Answer (score 2):

Cool, so it looks like even though the field is nullable, you still need to pass the "None" type through if you want to leave it null.

So

```
    {
    'id': 5,
    'application_form_id': 1,
    'section_id': 2,
    'type': 'long_text',
    'headline': 'headline 1',
    'description': 'Maximum 80 words.',
    'order': 4,
    'is_required': True       
}
```

Becomes

```
    {
    'id': 5,
    'application_form_id': 1,
    'section_id': 2,
    'type': 'long_text',
    'headline': 'headline 1',
    'description': 'Maximum 80 words.',
    'order': 4,
    'description': None,
    'is_required': True,
    'options': None       
}
```

Comment: Probably related, if not the cause: "When executing multiple sets of parameters, each dictionary must have the same set of keys; i.e. you cant have fewer keys in some dictionaries than others. This is because the Insert statement is compiled against the first dictionary in the list, and it’s assumed that all subsequent argument dictionaries are compatible with that statement." https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements

Comment: @IljaEverilä yeah that makes a ton of sense and lines up exactly with what I was experiencing. So for interest's sake, if I specified "none" for the nullable fields in the first dictionary, and left the nullable fields out in subsequent dictionaries for the ones that have no values, it should work, right? Or would it still break because they don't match the first dictionary?

Comment: Tbh I don't know. I guess it depends on how SQLA then accesses those dicts. If it uses `get()` or such, it should work. On the other hand it might blow up on `KeyError`, if they expect those keys to be there and don't then guard against it. The documentation seems to hint at the latter.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Cool, what exactly is the protocol here now? You answered my question, but in a comment. I want to mark yours as the correct answer, but can't. Could you create an answer, and then I'll accept it?